# hot to fix line graph broken image in ssrs line chart while rendering?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

In SSRS dashboard line graph is not loading after 70 + line graphs(applying group by for line graph). it it showing broken image? how to fix this issue?

Comment: plz refer similar error here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1464818-150-1.aspx

Comment: restarted ssrs reporting services but no use.

Comment: Udaya....you saying that SSRS is having issue rendering 70+ Lines in a graph?  You are asking it to render too much data, if you have 70+ unique lines to be rendered within a graph.  Anything more than 5 lines for a line graph, makes the graph less relevant and potentially confusing to those viewing it.